# Using an if statement to see if a button is clicked in Windows Forms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, button, listbox, click

I have a Windows Form application that is being used to practice the Bubble Sort algorithm.  Basically I have four different radio buttons which each displays a certain number of random integers in a listbox when clicked.  What I want is to be able to click a button that says "Sort" to then sort all the integers in that listbox.  Since each radio button displays different integers in the listbox, I have to do this under the radioButton1_CheckedChange method, so then I may have easy access to the random array that has been created for the listbox.  I am currently struggling with getting my code to make the button1_Clicked event handler to be set to "true" when the button is clicked.  Here's an excerpt of my code below to show you guys what I mean.

```
bool buttonClick = false;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//When button is clicked, button click is true
    {
        buttonClick = true;
    }

    private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)//Max 100 button
    {
        int smallMaxSize = 101;
        int[] array = new int[smallMaxSize];

        Random numGenerator = new Random();

        numGenerator.Next(smallMaxSize);

        for (int i=0; i<101; i++)//Generates 100 random numbers from 1-100
        {
            array[i] = numGenerator.Next(smallMaxSize);
            Numbers.Items.Add(array[i]);
        }   

        if (buttonClick == true)
        {
            Numbers.Items.Clear();
            int Out;
            int In;

            for (Out = smallMaxSize - 1; Out > 1; Out--)
            {
                for (In = 0; In < Out; In++)
                {
                    if (array[In] > array[In + 1])
                    {
                        int temp = array[In];
                        array[In] = array[In + 1];
                        array[In + 1] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

As you can see, I've set up a private bool for the button click, which is always set to false.  Under the button1_Click event handler, I have that change to true whenever the "Sort" button is clicked.  Then I have an "if" statement under the Radio Button method that says "if buttonClick == true, run this code".  When I run the code and click the "Sort" Button, nothing happens.  Anyone have any ideas that could lead me in the right direction?

Comment: If you want the sorting to occur when you click the button, then the sorting logic should be in the buttons click event handler.  And from there you can check which radio button is checked (it's not completely clear how the radio button fits in here though)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Forms is **event driven** programming meaning that things only happen when an event occurs, this is generally a user interaction with the form, but it can be a timer, loop, etc.

Your problem is that you have your Bubble Sort code in `radioButton1_CheckedChanged` method which will only fire when the `radioButton1` checked property changes. Basically what is happening is that when you click the radiobutton you are creating the random values then checking to see if the button was clicked, which obviously it hasn't been because you are still in the `radioButton1_CheckedChanged`.

You need to move your Bubble Sort code into `button1_Click` method OR you can click your Sort button first and then click a radiobutton.

```
int[] array;
int smallMaxSize = 101;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//When button is clicked, button click is true
{
    int Out;
    int In;

    for (Out = smallMaxSize - 1; Out > 1; Out--)
    {
        for (In = 0; In < Out; In++)
        {
            if (array[In] > array[In + 1])
            {
                int temp = array[In];
                    array[In] = array[In + 1];
                    array[In + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
}

private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)//Max 100 button
{
    Numbers.Items.Clear();
    array = new int[smallMaxSize];

    Random numGenerator = new Random();

    numGenerator.Next(smallMaxSize);

    for (int i=0; i<101; i++)//Generates 100 random numbers from 1-100
    {
        array[i] = numGenerator.Next(smallMaxSize);
        Numbers.Items.Add(array[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  This answer does make a lot of sense.  So I've modified the code so the bubble sort algorithm is under button1_Click and the random number generator is still under radioButton1_CheckedChanged.  Now what I'm struggling with is wiring up the bubble sort code to the listbox. I've tested the code by adding a Numbers.Clear() method in the bubble sort code ("Numbers" is the listbox), which worked when I clicked the button.  So I guess I'm wondering how to get the code to work for the items in the listbox now. I know I'm close, I just can't think up the logic for it :/

Comment: Well first you shouldn't have Numbers.Clear() in the button1_Click event because that will clear the numbers in the listbox that you want to sort which is obviously not what you want. You should be able to do a loop of all the numbers in the listbox with something like Numbers.Items(int index) and run your Bubble Sort algorithm on them.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does currently run the sort algorithm if you check one of your checkboxes. Thats because your sorting logic is inside the handler of the checkbox check event (the `radioButton1_CheckedChanged` method). That means all what's inside the `radioButton1_CheckedChanged` method will just run if you click the checkbox. But that's not what you want. If you want the sorting method to run when you click the button then it has to be inside the `button1_click` method.

Your bool variable is more or less useless.

Try this:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//When button is clicked, button click is true
    {
        int smallMaxSize = 101;
        int[] array = new int[smallMaxSize];

        Random numGenerator = new Random();

        numGenerator.Next(smallMaxSize);

        for (int i=0; i<101; i++)//Generates 100 random numbers from 1-100
        {
            array[i] = numGenerator.Next(smallMaxSize);
            Numbers.Items.Add(array[i]);
        }   

        if (buttonClick == true)
        {
            Numbers.Items.Clear();
            int Out;
            int In;

            for (Out = smallMaxSize - 1; Out > 1; Out--)
            {
                for (In = 0; In < Out; In++)
                {
                    if (array[In] > array[In + 1])
                    {
                        int temp = array[In];
                        array[In] = array[In + 1];
                        array[In + 1] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```